# Finding $\lim_{x \to \infty}\int_0^x{e^{-x^2+t^2}}\,dt$

Tags: calculus, integration, limits

If we aren’t able to solve the integral $\int e^{-x^2}\,dx$, then how is it possible to find the $\lim_{x \to \infty}\int_0^x{e^{-x^2+t^2}}\,dt$? This was given to me by my prof, and I asked him multiple times if it was able to be solved. He said yes, but I’m just not getting it. Any thoughts?

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Can you [edit] your question to include your thoughts and efforts on this problem? What have you tried, and where are you having difficulty? This will help people write an appropriate answer the addresses your problem. Questions that include this information tend to have a much better response.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Note that

$$\int_{0}^{x}{e^{-x^2+t^2}}\,dt=e^{-x^2}\int_{0}^{x}e^{t^2}\,dt=\frac{\int_{0}^{x}e^{t^2}\,dt}{e^{x^2}}$$

Now, to solve the limit, use [Fundamental Theorem of Calculus](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FundamentalTheoremsofCalculus.html) and [L'Hospital's Rule](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LHospitalsRule.html):
$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\int_{0}^{x}e^{t^2}\,dt}{e^{x^2}}=\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{e^{x^2}}{2xe^{x^2}}=0$$

Comment: Also using Fundamental Theorem of Calculus on the numerator.

Comment: Yup, it's perfect now. :)

Comment: Solid approach!  +1

Answer (score 3):

Here is, what I would say, a more standard analysis way. Admittedly a bit longer than applying l'Hospital, but maybe more instructive of why the limit is zero.

Let $0<\delta<1$ be fixed (but arbitrary). Then
$$
\int_0^x e^{-x^2+t^2}\,dt=\int_0^{\delta x} e^{-x^2+t^2}\,dt+\int_{\delta x}^xe^{-x^2+t^2}\,dt
$$
The first integral is estimated by the worst value of the integrand (attained when $t=\delta x$) times the length of the interval,
$$
\int_0^{\delta x} e^{-x^2+t^2}\,dt\leq \delta x e^{x^2(\delta^2-1)}
$$
For the second one, we note that when $\delta x<t<x$, $1/t<1/(\delta x)$, and so
$$
\begin{aligned}
\int_{\delta x}^xe^{-x^2+t^2}\,dt&=e^{-x^2}\int_{\delta x}^{x}\frac{1}{t} te^{t^2}\,dt\\
&<e^{-x^2}\frac{1}{\delta x}\int_{\delta x}^xte^{t^2}\,dt\\
&=e^{-x^2}\frac{1}{\delta x}\Bigl[\frac{1}{2}e^{t^2}\Bigr]_{\delta x}^x\\
&=\frac{1}{2\delta x}\bigl(1-e^{x^2(\delta^2-1)}\bigr).
\end{aligned}
$$
All in all
$$
0\leq \int_0^x e^{-x^2+t^2}\,dt<\delta x e^{x^2(\delta^2-1)}+\frac{1}{2\delta x}\bigl(1-e^{x^2(\delta^2-1)}\bigr).
$$
The squeeze theorem on limits now gives

> $$\lim_{x\to+\infty}\int_0^x e^{-x^2+t^2}\,dt=0.$$

Comment: This is also nice. +1

Answer (score 2):

Let $I(x)$ be the integral defined by

$$I(x)=\int_0^xe^{t^2}\,dt$$

First, split the integral into the sum

$$I(x)=\int_0^1e^{t^2}\,dt+\int_1^xe^{t^2}\,dt \tag 1$$

Now, integrating by parts the second integral in $(1)$ with $u=t^{-1}$ and $v=\frac12e^{t^2}$ reveals

$$I(x)=\int_0^1e^{t^2}\,dt+\left(\frac{e^{x^2}}{2x}-\frac{e}{2}\right)+\frac12\int_1^x\frac{e^{t^2}}{t^2}\,dt \tag 2$$

For $x\ge 1$, we have

$$|I(x)|\le \left(\frac{e^{x^2}}{2x}+\frac{e}{2}\right)+\frac12\frac{e^{x^2}}{x^2}\le \frac32 \frac{e^{x^2}}{x}$$

and therefore,

$$\left|e^{-x^2}I(x)\right|\le \frac{3}{2x}\to 0\,\,\text{as}\,\,x\to \infty$$

---

**NOTE:**

We can develop an asymptotic expansion for "large $x$"  by using Cauchy's Integral Theorem to rewrite $I(x)$ as

$$\begin{align}
I(x)&=\int_0^xe^{t^2}\,dt\\\\
&=\int_0^{i\infty} e^{z^2}\,dz+\int_{i\infty}^xe^{z^2}\,dz\\\\
&=\frac{i\sqrt \pi}{2}+\int_{i\infty}^xe^{z^2}\,dz \tag 3\\\\
\end{align}$$

Next, we integrate by parts the integral on the right-hand side of $(3)$ with $u=z^{-1}$ and $v=\frac12 e^{z^2}$ and obtain

$$I(x)=\frac{i\sqrt \pi}{2}+\frac{e^{x^2}}{2x}+\frac12\int_{i\infty}^x\frac{e^{z^2}}{z^2}\,dz \tag 4$$

Integrating by parts the integral on the right-hand side of $(4)$ with $u=z^{-3}$ and $v=\frac12 e^{z^2}$ yields

$$I(x)=\frac{i\sqrt \pi}{2}+\frac{e^{x^2}}{2x}+\frac{e^{x^2}}{2^2\,x^3}+\frac34\int_{i\infty}^x\frac{e^{z^2}}{z^4}\,dz\tag 5 $$

We proceed by continuing to integrate by parts and find that

$$I(x)=\frac{i\sqrt \pi}{2}+\frac{e^{x^2}}{2x}\left(1+\sum_{n=1}^{N}\frac{(2n-1)!!}{2^n\,x^{2n}}\right)+\frac{(2N+1)!!}{2^{N+1}}\int_{i\infty}^x\frac{e^{z^2}}{z^{2(N+1)}}\,dz \tag 6$$

Using $(2\ell-1)!!=\frac{(2\ell)!}{2^{\ell}\,\ell!}$, we can write $(6)$ as

$$I(x)=\frac{i\sqrt \pi}{2}+\frac{e^{x^2}}{2x}\left(1+\sum_{n=1}^{N}\frac{(2n)!}{n!\,(2x)^{2n}}\right)+\frac{(2N+1)!}{2^{2N+1}\,N!}\int_{i\infty}^x\frac{e^{z^2}}{z^{2(N+1)}}\,dz \tag 7$$

Note that for real values of $x$, the left-hand side of $(7)$ is purely real.  Therefore, we have

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{I(x)=\frac{e^{x^2}}{2x}\left(1+\sum_{n=1}^{N}\frac{(2n)!}{n!\,(2x)^{2n}}\right)+\frac{(2N+1)!}{2^{2N+1}\,N!}\,\,\text{Re}\left(\int_{i\infty}^x\frac{e^{z^2}}{z^{2(N+1)}}\,dz\right) } \tag 8$$

It is important to realize that the partial sums in $(8)$ diverge as $N\to \infty$ for every value of $x$.  While this seems at first glance to make the expansion useless, this is not the case.  We can show, that the integral of the right-hand side of $(8)$ satisfies

$$\left|\int_{i\infty}^x\frac{e^{z^2}}{z^{2(N+1)}}\,dz\right|= O\left(\frac{e^{x^2}}{x^{2N+1}}\right)$$

Therefore, $(8)$ provides a perfectly suitable expansion for large $x$.

A word of caution is that for fixed $x$, the accuracy of the expansion eventually worsens with increasing $N$.  However, for fixed $N$, the accuracy of the expansion improves with increasing $x$.

Comment: Yes, this is perfect. +1

Comment: Please let me know how I can improve my answer. I really want to give you the best answer I can. Happy Holidays. - Mark

Answer (score 0):

More generally,
consider
$I(f)
=\lim_{x \to \infty}
\frac1{f(x)}\int_0^x f(t)dt
$
where $f(x) \to \infty$.

I'll try to find
a condition on $f$
such that
$I(f) = 0$.

By L'Hopital's rule,
$I(f)
=\lim_{x \to \infty}
\frac1{f(x)}\int_0^x f(t)dt
=\lim_{x \to \infty}
\frac{f(x)}{f'(x)}
$
if this limit exists.

Therefore,
if
$\lim_{x \to \infty}
\frac{f(x)}{f'(x)}
=0
$,
then
$I(f) = 0$.

If
$f(x) = e^{x^a}$
with
$a > 1$
(the OP's case is $a=2$),
then
$f'(x)
=ax^{a-1}e^{x^a}
$,
so
$\frac{f(x)}{f'(x)}
=\frac1{ax^{a-1}}
\to 0
$
as $x \to \infty$.